# Can and should this question be salvaged?

Tags: discussion

[What if someone else sins for you](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/73407/what-if-someone-else-sins-for-you) is put on hold (rightly so) for being a truth question of the form "Is X a sin?".

I think this question is interesting and could be salvaged if it is reformulated as "Are there examples from the Bible where behavior X is punished?" which seems to avoid the Truth issue and is just a question for an example from the text. That seems answerable. If there are no examples it still does not mean X is a sin, nor does a punishment necessarily mean X is a sin *today*. But for some issues it points in a certain direction.

So... can and should this question, or others like it, be salvaged in this way? Or is too close to the unwanted "Is X a sin?"?

Comment: What you're proposing is what we call a verse search question, and would also be off-topic. Because what constitutes a valid example is very much a matter of personal interpretation.

Comment: @curiousdannii Hmm okay additionally it would be not really possible to answer as "No, there are no examples", right?

Comment: Maybe for some questions, but I think the majority would have some grey areas. The whole category is risky, and a question would have to make its case well that it can be answered objectively.

Comment: Can someone kill another person for you? I think not. Leave it closed. It would be extremely hard to make this question on topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could ask from a Natural Law perspective, but this question makes a doctrinal assumption that says every sin is enumerated in the Bible. If there was such a group, which is doubtful.  I don't think there's any way to answer the question objectively, it is off topic on at least 3 levels.

- is X a sin
- where is it in the Bible
- not scoped

What one could ask ([on another site, perhaps](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com)), is why did God want to kill Balaam rather than Balak?